# etymology of "sesquicentennial"

Tags: etymology

The word *sesquicentennial* means "150th anniversary". When I first found this out, I thought about the prefix **sesqui-** and what it could mean.

My first thought was that it meant 6/4 = 1.5, because it seemed that the syllables matched up with "six" and "quart". After deciding that that must be right, I decided to check online. To my surprise, it appears that the prefix [literally means "half and"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesqui).

Was my first revelation a complete coincidence or is there actually a legitimate reason for what I noticed?

Comment: 6/4 would be a strange choice; the more common way of expressing that fraction is 3/2.

Comment: A strange choice, yes, but not entirely impossible.

Comment: Gamblers always refer to the relevant odds as 6/4 (pronounced  six to four), not three to two. Old joke about the bookie teaching his baby to count : One, six-to-four, two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to [Lewis and Short's "A Latin Dictionary"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsesqui), the derivation is actually:

> **sesquĭ (sesque )**,
>   **I**. num. adv. [perh. contr. from semis-qui], one half more, more by a half. As a separate word it occurs only once: “**ut necesse sit partem pedis aut aequalem alteri parti aut altero tanto aut sesqui esse majorem**,” Cic. Or. 56, 188. But freq. joined in one word with designations of number or quantity, with the signif. of once and a half. Joined with numerals (octavus and tertius), like the Gr. ἐπί (in ἐπόγδοος, ἐπίτριτος, etc.), it denotes an integer and such a fraction over as the numeral designates; v. sesquioctavus, etc.

so I'd be inclined to think "coincidence".  From such things are folk etymologies made.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, *sesqui-* is a contraction of *semis* and *que*

According to [etymonline:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=sesquicentennial&searchmode=none)

> "pertaining to a century and a half," 1880, from L. sesqui- "one and a half" (from semis "a half" + -que "and") + centennial (q.v.). First recorded ref. is to Baltimore's.
>   sesquipedalian

Also [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sesqui-)

> [from Latin, contraction of semi-  + as as ² + -que  and]

So, there aren't related, and I would say it is just coincidence.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say, sorry if that didn't come across.

Comment: Um, edited my answer to answer the question. :)